# Form validation by JS

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I wanna validate my textareas in my form.. But I've got a problem, just tried to validate one of my text areas, but after that my form don't work - I made local and session storage and hiding/showing my radiobuttons by checking checkboxes.. But after adding my function to form it doesn't work.. I don't know where is a problem

My JS file, there save and load are for local and sessionstorage, toggle functions make my attributes and radions hidden/visible. Check functions validate one of my textAreas.

```js
function toggleAttributes(checkbox, radios, attribute, attributeValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i += 1) {
    // If checkbox is checked, set the attribute and the attribute value. If not, remove the attribute
    checkbox.checked === true ? radios[i].setAttribute(attribute, attributeValue) : radios[i].removeAttribute(attribute);
  }
}

function toggleRadios(el, id) {
  var radiosSelector = `#${id} input[type='radio']`,
    container = document.getElementById(id),
    radios = document.querySelectorAll(radiosSelector);
  container.classList.toggle("hide");
  toggleAttributes(el, radios, "required", "");
}
var i;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
function check()
{
var ok=true;

regLast = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;

if (!regLast.test(document.getElementById("lastName")))
{
    ok=false;
    document.getElementsByClassName("lastNameCheck").innerHTML= "Put valid data";
}
else
    document.getElementsByClassName("lastNameCheck").innerHTML="";

return ok;
}
```

```html
<form "needs-validation" onsubmit "return check()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for ="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "lastName" placeholder = "Podaj nazwisko" name = "nazwisko" />
      <div class="invalid-tooltip lastNameCheck">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Choose dishes:
    </p>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkGlowne" data-target="pierwsze" onclick="toggleRadios(this, 'pierwsze')">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkGlowne">Main</label>
    </div>
    <p>
      Main dishes
    </p>
    <div id = "pierwsze" class = "hide">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="1" name = "pierwsze">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="1">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="2" name = "pierwsze">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="2">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="3" name = "pierwsze">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="3">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="4" name = "pierwsze">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="4">4</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

If it's possible I want to: validate my form and if it's correct i wanna send my form to local and sessionstorage and show alert, but when it's incorrect i just wanna to put tooltips that input is wrong.
I have one function to save and alert my inputs.. How can I connect it?

Comment: It's always a very bad idea to use non-English variable names etc. Makes the code so much harder to read for people not speaking the language used. I for my own part would never dig into such code to give an answer.

Comment: Should I edit all these names for English there or ask another question with English names?

Comment: I just wanted to show other functions - these for hiding/showing checkboxes and radiobuttons and these for adding and removing from session/localstorage

Comment: @PaulStenne 

I just edited my post, now variables are in English and i deleted some code.

Comment: Just 4 fun: have a look @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/o6ej8utb/embedded/result,js,html,css